# R Machine learning server - RevoScaleR error

Tags: r, machine-learning, ubuntu-16.04, microsoft-r

I have updated R (Microsoft Machine Learning Server R) in Ubuntu and after the update the RevoScaleR package stopped working. I try to see the log but it doesn't exist. Does anyone know it?

**EDIT**: I have found out that libRblas.so is not found but it exists in /runtime/R/lib

```
library(RevoScaleR)
C++ runtime exception caught: could not open FIFO /tmp/Rtmp9FpGRx/RevoFIFO.140827.2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RevoScaleR’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RevoScaleR', details:
  call: dyn.load(linkDllName)
  error: fatal error: RevoScaleR cannot be used in this R session anymore, if possible restart R session
error code 127, detailed error message might be found in: /tmp/Rtmp9FpGRx/stdoutrppZXg (standard output) and /tmp
```

The output of `"RevoScaleR" %in% dir(.libPaths())` is `TRUE`.

Comment: What's the output of `dir(.libPaths())`

Comment: Or more explicitly `"RevoScaleR" %in% dir(.libPaths())`

Comment: The output is TRUE

Comment: Hey Leo! You wrote: "I have updated R in Ubuntu" - what R did you update" CRANR, Microsoft Open R, Microsoft Machine Learning Server R?

Comment: @NielsBerglund I have updated Microsoft Machine Learning Server R. By the way, I have found out that libRblas.so is not found but it exists in /runtime/R/lib

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that after the update, the libraries magically disappeared. I solved it by manually copying the necessary libraries:

```
sudo cp /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/runtime/R/lib/libmkl_gnu_thread.so /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/libraries/RServer/RevoScaleR/rxLibs/x64/libmkl_gnu_thread.so
sudo cp /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/runtime/R/lib/libRblas.so /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/libraries/RServer/RevoScaleR/rxLibs/x64/libRblas.so
sudo cp /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/runtime/R/lib/libmkl_gf_lp64.so /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/libraries/RServer/RevoScaleR/rxLibs/x64/libmkl_gf_lp64.so
sudo cp /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/runtime/R/lib/libRlapack.so /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/libraries/RServer/RevoScaleR/rxLibs/x64/libRlapack.so
sudo cp /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/runtime/R/lib/libmkl_core.so /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/libraries/RServer/RevoScaleR/rxLibs/x64/libmkl_core.so
sudo cp /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/runtime/R/lib/libmkl_vml_mc3.so /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/libraries/RServer/RevoScaleR/rxLibs/x64/libmkl_vml_mc3.so
sudo cp /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/runtime/R/lib/libmkl_vml_def.so /opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.2.1/libraries/RServer/RevoScaleR/rxLibs/x64/libmkl_vml_def.so
```